# Could the pronoun 'one' be used without an article (or a determiner)?

Tags: grammaticality

I'd like to know if it is possible for the pronoun **'one'** to be used without any specifier or article as in the following sentence:

> *"Why do you like Chinese food?"
>
> "How about ( ) Australian **one**?"*

In the second sentence, **"one"** substitutes its antecedent "food".

I made an assumption that if **"food"** is an uncountable noun then **"one"** does not need an article in this sentence .

Is my assumption right? Is the pronoun **one** always countable? Or it becomes uncountable when its antecedent is uncountable?

Comment: _Food_ being an uncountable noun, it can't take _one_, which is strictly for singular count nouns. So the article is irrelevant. The correct sentence is _How about Australian (food)?_ With a mass noun, you can just delete it, but with a count noun you have to instantiate it.

Comment: *Of Chinese food and Australian food I only like the first (one).* Even here, *one* apparently does not stand for the mass noun *food* but for the first *option* mentioned in the  sentence. Is this correct, @JohnLawler.

Answer (score 1):

*One* doesn't take an article if:

- it's a determiner itself.  "I took one look at it and left."
- it refers to a person and is being used in a purely abstract sense.  "One does not learn English in a day."

Otherwise it needs "the" in front of it.  You'll never say "a one" unless *one* refers to the numeral 1.

Answer (score -1):

Or, **"How about the Australian food ?"** could be an option.

Comment: No, that would sound extremely awkward. The definite article should not be there.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. A good answer is complete and explains why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that lack support may be removed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].